# Get data from Firebase db, comes back without key value

Tags: json, rest, firebase

I am retrieving data from Firebase db using REST call. So i have a data looking like this

```
user
{
    123456: 
     {
       Email: "test@hotmail.com", 
       Password: "John Doe"
     }

    654321: 
     {
       Email: "test2@hotmail.com", 
       Password: "Jane Doe"
     }
}
```

The query I used is

`firebaseurl/user.json?orderBy="Email"&equalTo="test@hotmail.com"`

Is it possible if I query without the key value `123456` being retrieve? Because whenever I try to use the data, for instance `console.log(user.Email)`, I am getting undefined. But when I do it like`console.log(user[123456].Email)` then will I get the result I desire.

May I know if there's a way to do it? Or a way to access to the child element without `user[keyvalue]`.

Comment: How do you retrieve this record? what is your query?

Comment: @AlexMounir updated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is expected only single record in return you can use:
`const user = obj[Object.keys(rslt)[0]]`

Or you can loop over the keys

```
const usersArr = Object.keys(rslt).map(usr => {
    ... manipulate usr 
    return usr
})
```

Comment: Hi Alex, may I ask if i would like to retrieve all users without key value and store in `this.users`. Would it be possible?

Comment: yes, remove the equalTo and it should return all users

Comment: I did that. But it returns along with key value. I tried to do the `obj[Object.keys(rslt)[0]]` but it only work with 1 data due to the [0]. Is there a way to do for all users?

Comment: The other section of the answer deals with the multiple: this.users = `Object.keys(rslt).map(usr => usr)`. This means you are looping the the array of the keys of the retrieved object and mapping the users to an array

Comment: Yeap, understood on that part. But it only takes in the key value instead. And not the other data such as email address etc. Is it possible to do in a such way that i don't take in the key value, instead i take in the email address & password only of the 2 data.